# Unidad de Fomento (CLF/UF) and money gem

Tags: ruby, format, currency

I've been struggling to understand how does the `money` gem formats the Unidad de Fomento. I've tested the version `6.5` and the `6.7` and both seems to present odd formats:

```rb
# Money 6.5

usd = Money.new(243, 'USD')
usd.to_f #=> 2.43
usd.format #=> "$2.43"

clf = Money.new(243, 'CLF')
clf.to_f #=> 243
clf.format #=> "CLF243"

# Money 6.7

usd = Money.new(243, 'USD')
usd.to_f #=> 2.43
usd.format #=> "$2.43"

clf = Money.new(243, 'CLF')
clf.to_f #=> 0.0243
clf.format #=> "CLF0.0243"
```

Is it meant to be this way or it is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I've got it. I'm a fool who thinks we lived in a world of cents like USD or EUR (base 10 exponent 2, `10^2 cents` equals 1 unit of the currency). There are many currencies that do not have any kind of minor currencies like the Japanse Yen (JPY) and there are also currencies with no base 10 at all. This article in the wikipedia explains it very well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

So, in my examples it seems that a long time ago the CLF was a currency with exponent 0, so it hasn't any type of minor currency. 2.34 was an invalid amount so `money` converted it into 234. The ISO changed, and then CLF was converted into a currency with exponent 4.

This comment on the `money` issue tracker solved my issue: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/issues/614#issuecomment-194813943

Answer (score 0):

It was an intentional change introduced with version **6.6**. 
See the [changelog](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and the [commit](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/commit/bfa7108e1d085f7518ff979db4b8c9cb1b1b1e3f) on GitHub. Unfortunately there is no hint as of why it was done.

Answer (score 0):

Money >= 6.6:

```
currency_id = "CLF"
subunits = Money::Currency.new(currency_id).subunit_to_unit
clf = Money.new(243 * subunits, currency_id)
clf.format #=> "UF243.0000"
```